# How to use node-mongodb-connection for connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I make connection to my database like the following:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true}));
mongoClient.open(function (err, mongoClient) {
  var db = mongoClient.db('db_name');
  db.authenticate('user', 'password', function () {err, result} {
     if (err || !result) return console.log('error');

     app.use(express.session({       
        store: new MongoStore({
          db: db
        })
     });
  });
});
```

And I want to share db connection with MongoStore but it's seem not work. How should I do that?

**EDIT:** I'm using authentication on my database but after new MongoStore() get executes I'm getting the following error:

```
not authorized for query on site.system.indexes
```

Comment: There is an `});` missing for `app.use`.

Comment: Added it as answer to make it clear. If that is not the problem, please clarify "it's seem not work". Any error messages?

Answer (score 5):

This is how it works for me,

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db_name";
var dbOptions = {
server:{
    'auto_reconnect': true,
    'poolSize': 20,
    socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}  
    }
}
// For long running applictions it is often prudent to enable keepAlive. Without it,
// after some period of time you may start to see "connection closed" errors for what 
// seems like no reason.
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, dbOptions, function(err, db) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);            
    }

app.use(express.session({
        store:new mongoStore({db: db}),
        secret: 'secret'
    }));
})
```

This works perfectly for me and it will not give you not authorized issues as well. Previously we don't need to give keepAlive option and it works perfectly witout it but with a release of mongodb 2.4 for long running applications we need to give keepAlive option otherwise we keep getting connection closed or not authorized sort of errors.

Comment: I think the problem in connect-mongo module. https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/70

Comment: yup it is but if you set keepalive option connect-mongo works fine. I am using the same configration in production without an issue.

Comment: http://postnikapp.com/ it's a free iphone app having a back-end in node.js and mongodb

Comment: How many users do you have every day and did you have any memory leaks on using node-monhodb-native ?

Comment: I have used node-mongodb-native in 2 to 3 projects without an issue. It's an offical mongodb drvier for node.js supported by 10gen.

Comment: why not you try it yourself and see does it working for you or not?

Comment: My project in development yet. I hope I'll try soon. What do you use for session storing?

Comment: I have used mongodb for session storing you can use redis as well.